# django admin - custom fields radio - admin.HORIZONTAL not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have this custom field `image_choice` in django admin as a radio select.

```
IMG_CHOICES = (
   ('embed', _('Embed code')),
   ('file', _('Upload image')),
   ('link', _('Image Link'))
)

class BlogArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Media:
       js = ('js/myjs.js')
   image_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IMG_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)


class BlogArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = BlogArticleForm
   fields = ['title', 'description', 'image_choice', 'image_embed', 'image_file', 'image_link']


admin.site.register(models.BlogArticle, BlogArticleAdmin)
```

I cannot get these radio buttons line up horizontally.

I tried:

```
radio_fields = {'image_choice': admin.HORIZONTAL}
```

and

```
radio_fields = {form.image_choice: admin.HORIZONTAL}
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
type object "BlogArticleForm" has no attribute 'image_choice'
```

how can I achieve this?

this is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/06b11b617e7d3439bb36b65d1cacd4cc75f36c69/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L214).
So I guess it should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import get_ul_class

class BlogArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
   image_choice = forms.ChoiceField(
                            choices=IMG_CHOICES,
                            widget=widgets.AdminRadioSelect(
                               attrs={'class': get_ul_class(admin.HORIZONTAL)}
                            ))
```

**UPD**: I'm stupid :(
It says: `if 'widget' not in kwargs:` bla-bla-bla adds widget. So this should work with no widget:

```
image_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IMG_CHOICES)

# And set 
radio_fields = {'image_choice': admin.HORIZONTAL}
```

Comment: this just makes a dropdown. i need horizontal radio buttons

Comment: widgets.AdminRadioSelect makes dropdown?

Comment: ``image_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IMG_CHOICES)`` is making dropdown

Comment: Oh, I should be more clear. Use widget (manually) OR do not AND radio_fields = {'image_choice': admin.HORIZONTAL} (make django set it).